# Cloning a Linux Server

Tags: linux

I have two servers, A and B. I would like to clone server A to B. A is running Linux, and they are both remote, I dont have a physical access to them

What is the best way to approach this?

Thanks,

Comment: How do you access server B? Is it also running linux?

Comment: `dd` with `netcat` is probably the more robust option, not the safest though.

Comment: Do you really want to clone them, as the answers here will help you do, or are you wanting to mirror content and functionality of a web or other type of server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup partition on new server, copy everything over and write boot loader + adjust fstab and kernel (or if default modular kernel is used no need to touch anything) and network related configuration.

Or install the other system, then install all packages installed on first system,and move over datasets whatever they are; database dumps, home directories, spool directories... anything that you might need from server A to B .

In first approach you will get identical system and just adjust few details... in second one you will install necessary components and thou something might be missing initially but you will clean up a bit and start fresh with just the data you need.

To transport data there are many options
ftp
scp/sftp
rsync
tar && netcat
dd && netcat

off all the options I suggest using rsync, or tar with netcat since it's least data to transfer and you get to keep the permissions from system A.